# sql taking < 1 sec to run in sql developer, 37 on the application side

Tags: optimization, jdbc, oracle-12c

As the title says, we have a big discrepency between a sql query we're running from our java application (jdbc thin client) and the same query run in sql developer.

I clear the cache of the query before running it locally as follows:

`exec DBMS_SHARED_POOL.PURGE ('000000029F12AE38, 3000986076', 'C');`

The address and hash values are retrieved from the `v$sqlarea` view. I always get the freshest data to proceed. (If you think it's not enough to flush the cache, please kindly let me know)

Query:

```
select
  t.zoo_equipment_type || ': ' || t.zoo_equipment_type_descr equipment,
  t.zoo_service_descr_1 service_descr,
  tr.resourceid,
  trunc(t.startdate) start_date, 
  trunc(t.finishdate) finish_date
from eai_taskrsrc tr
inner join eai_task t on tr.snapshot = t.snapshot and tr.activityobjectid = t.task_id
inner join eai_project p on t.snapshot = p.snapshot and t.proj_id = p.proj_id and p.eai_snapshot_type = 'P'
inner join (
  select
    eai_project.eai_snapshot_project,
    'P',
    max(eai_project.eai_snapshot_period) max_period
  from
    eai_project
    join eai_res_spread on eai_res_spread.snapshot = eai_project.snapshot
    join eai_task on eai_task.snapshot = eai_res_spread.snapshot and eai_task.task_id = eai_res_spread.task_id
  where
     eai_snapshot_project IN (:1 ) 
    and eai_snapshot_type = 'P'
  group by
    eai_project.eai_snapshot_project,
    'P'
) max_period on max_period.max_period = p.eai_snapshot_period 
  and max_period.eai_snapshot_project = p.eai_snapshot_project
where 
   p.eai_snapshot_project IN (:2 ) 
  and  t.zoo_unit IN (:3 )
  and  1 = 1 
  and  1 = 1 
  and  1 = 1 
  and  1 = 1 
  and  1 = 1 
  and  t.zoo_equipment_type IN (:4 ,:5 )
  and  tr.resourceid IN (:6 ,:7 ,:8 ,:9 ,:10 ,:11 ,:12 ,:13 ,:14 ,:15 ,:16 ,:17 ,:18 ,:19 ,:20 ,:21 ,:22 ,:23 ,:24 ,:25 ,:26 ,:27 ,:28 ,:29 )
group by 
  t.zoo_equipment_type, 
  t.zoo_equipment_type_descr,
  t.zoo_service_descr_1,
  tr.resourceid,
  trunc(t.startdate),
  trunc(t.finishdate)
order by 
  t.zoo_equipment_type,
  t.zoo_service_descr_1,
  tr.resourceid
;
```

Explain plan from SQLDEVELOPER:

[image]

Explain plan from Oracle Enterprise Manager:

[image]

They look alike, although not exactly the same. I don't know why, since both queries are equivalent (I took the one in EM and replaced the placeholders with the real values from the application).
But what really troubles me is that the time spent, according to enterprise manager, is almost 100% CPU, 37 out of the 37 seconds.

Hard drive activity flat, and total buffer reads 475k.

Do you have an idea why this is happening? I restarted my whole VM, application server, database... just to make sure, but it didn't change anything.

Thanks

Comment: How many rows it is supposed to return? Once results are displayed in SQLDeveloper, click on the result grid and hit CTRL+END to retrieve ALL rows not just the first batch. Compare THAT timing with app. Because your app could be fetching ALL rows returned by  the query and SQLDeveloper may be fetching just first X (partial result set) rows.

Comment: What is value for cursor_sharing parameter ?

Comment: @a1ex07 `EXACT`

Comment: @Raj 142 rows returned, it's pretty much instant anyway

Comment: @Sebas: When you run it from SQLDeveloper with replaced placeholders execution plan is very likely different compared when it's running from application - you are using bind variables in the app (which is considered good practice), and literals in SQLDeveloper.  But your query is quite complex with lots of bind variables (and possibly data skew) which can cause optimizer pick a wrong plan and stick to it - especially if you're running Oralce prior to 11g (11g and higher somehow improved bind peeking)

Comment: @a1ex07 yeah, must be this...

Comment: @Sebas: I'd first try replacing bind variables with literals (for this particular query) in application if it's possible. The query doesn't look like it's supposed to get executed too often, so it might be ok for your system. Secondly, you can create outline for this query. Another option is to optimize the statement with DBMS_SQLTUNE or DBMS_ADVISOR packages either directly or through EM.

Comment: @a1ex07 Ok, thanks for the advices. Out of pressure a coworker decided to rewrite the query differently so unfortunately I cannot test all this anymore. However, I will do it next time we have a similar problem.

Comment: Don't look at an explain plan, that might not be accurate. Run DBMS_XPLAN instead - it should be accurate enough to compare with the real time sql monitoring report you see in OEM. Or even better, just run the real time report in OEM for the java session and the sql developer session. One last thing, make sure your NLS variables are identical between the two programs.